# Cannot deserialize Restsharp response when the response is a raw string

Tags: .net, reflection, json.net, restsharp

I have a method similar to this where I execute requests and deserialize generic objects.

```
public T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
{
    request.AddParameter("AccountSid", _accountSid, ParameterType.UrlSegment); // used on every request
    var response = _client.Execute<T>(request);

    return response.Data;
}
```

The responses are deserialized like this:

```
public T Deserialize<T>(IRestResponse response) => return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);
```

I also have a class like this:

```
public class SomeResponse
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot deserialize the response for some requests since for some reason it is only a raw string not inside a JSON object. The response looks like this:

```
"abc123"
```

Most of the API that I am fetching data from is returning JSON objects so it works fine. I would like to avoid creating another Execute method just for that edge case.

I have started something like this but it seems a bit hacky. I feel there should be a simpler way to do this

```
 public T Deserialize<T>(IRestResponse response)
 {
        try
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);
        }
        catch
        {
            var content = response.Content;
            response.Content = $"{{ \"Id\" : {response.Content} }}";
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);
        }        
 }
```

Comment: In your edge case, what is the ContentType on the response?  Is it still "application/json" or something else?  Also, is the plain string always guaranteed to represent an ID on your `T`, or is it possible that it will represent something else?

Comment: The ContentType is still application/json. I think there are a few more endpoints that return a string so I am thinking of generalising the response object a bit more so it contains a "stringresponse" property instead of a specific "id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this using this method for now. There is only one method that returns a raw string. A better solution is still appreciated.

```
public T Deserialize<T>(IRestResponse response)
{
    try
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);
    }
    catch
    {
        if (typeof(T) != typeof(SomeResponse))
        {
           throw;
        }
        response.Content = $"{{ \"Id\" : {response.Content} }}";
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);
     }
}
```

other alternative is this

```
public T Deserialize<T>(IRestResponse response)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(SomeResponse))
    {
        response.Content = $"{{ \"Id\" : {response.Content} }}";
    }
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);
}
```